# Combinatorics: Number of possible 8 Characters words from Alphabets

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I found following Problem in Introductory Combinatorics text book:

**How many eight-letter words can be constructed by using the 26 letters of the alphabet if each word contains three vowels? It is understood that there is no restriction on the number of times a letter can be used in a  word**

Self Attempt:
I tried to solve the problem in following manners:
There are 5C3 ways we can select 3 vowels from the alphabet and 21C5 ways to select 5 consonant from 21 consonants. For each such 8 characters selection we can arrange the word in $8^8$ ways (as repetition of character is allowed).
My answer: $5C3 \cdot 21C5 \cdot 8^8$

But textbook has the following answer: $8C5 \cdot 5^3 \cdot 21^5$

Could you please help me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The textbook is saying "choose the $5$ out of $8$ positions for consonants (so $3$ for vowels), then choose the $3$ vowels possibly with repetition and the $5$ consonants possibly with repetition"

$^{5}C_3$ would be choosing three distinct vowels in any order rather than the $5^3$ since order matters and repetitions are allowed, and similarly $^{21}C_5$ should be $21^5$ for the same reason.

I am not clear what your $8^8$ was intended to be.  If the question had prohibited repeated letters, the answer would have been $8!\,^{5}C_3\, ^{21}C_5$

Comment: Have updated my question. It was a typing mistake. My final answer was 5C3 * 21C5 * 8^8

Comment: Yes - I see.  I have edited my answer

Comment: 8^8 means, There are 8 possible choices for each letter for each position in 8 letter word. Since there is no restriction on number of times a letter can be used, I think repetition is allowed.

Comment: @fluty $8^8$ would count for example the possibility of the same consonant being used $8$ times, which would preclude there being $3$ vowels, and many similar cases.  Looked at another way, you have chosen $3$ distinct vowels and $5$ distinct consonants in your $\,^{5}C_3\, ^{21}C_5$ but if you do not use them all then how do know which ones were the unused ones you chose?

Comment: Thats so true. I understand your point. Can we say something instead: For vowels 8c3*3! i.e Select 3 slots out of 8 and arrange letters in possible ways. 5^5 for arranging  consonants. 3!*8c3*5^5. But it does not into account that vowel can be repeated more than once.

Comment: It is $21^5$ for arranging consonants and $5^3$ for arranging vowels which when multiplied by $\,^8C_3 =\,^8C_5$ gives the textbook answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133933/discussion-between-fluty-and-henry).

Comment: I do not do chat

Comment: @Henrry Thanks. I understand your solution. You are selecting letters position from the 8 letter word and then arranging vowels/consonants on those positions. But i guess the way I was approaching the question by selecting letters from alphabets (rather than selecting letters position from word)  wont get me to answer.

Comment: Thats because repetition is allowed